# Distance between a point and a disk in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $$X=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} ; x^{2}+y^{2}<1\right\}.$$ If $a=(5,0)$, show that $d(a,X)=4$.

My attempt so far: I need to find the infimum of the set $S_m = \{d(z, a): z \in X\}$, so using the Euclidean metric I end up with the following equation: for $z \in X$ $$d(z,a)=\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2} = c, c \in \mathbb{R}.$$ Solving for $y^{2}< 1-x^{2}$ and $x<1$ we have that $$\dfrac{26-c^{2}}{10} < 1 \Rightarrow c>4.$$

With this, we see that 4 is a lower bound of $S_{m}$ but it's enough to say that $d(a, X) = 4$?

$d(a,X)$ = infimum of $\{d(a,x): x \in X\}$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: positive part of distance from point to center minus the radius of the disc

Comment: "... but it's enough to say that $d(a,X)=4$?"  Depends on the details of your definition of distance between a point and a set.  That definition should be added to your question.

Comment: I do not quite understand the "solving for $y^2<1-x^2$ and $x<1$" part. Using these 2 inequalities we get $c=\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2}<\sqrt{(x-5)^2+1-x^2}=\sqrt{26-10x}$, so $c^2<26-10x$. We get an upper bound but not a lower bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$
d(z,a)=\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2}\ge\sqrt{(x-5)^2}=|x-5|=5-x>4
$$

which holds for any $z=(x,y)\in X$. Hence $4$ is a lower bound for $S_m$.

Meanwhile, $4$ is the greatest lower bound since, fixing $y=0$, we have $d((x,0),a)=\sqrt{(x-5)^2}=5-x$, so we can have a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $1$ (e.g., $x_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$) which causes $d((x_n,0),a)\to 4$. Thus $4$ must be the greatest lower bound.